# MKMapView auto zooming out animation

Tags: ios, swift, location, mkmapview, swift4

I need to create `ViewController` with `MKMapView`. When it opens, there are should appear current location and slowly zooming out for 10 seconds (or less, it doesn't matter actually). And when animation completed application should perform segue to the next `ViewController`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "direct" method for setting a zoom level. You can, however, simulate this by setting the distance, which causes the image to resize.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D noLocation;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(noLocation, 500, 500);
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];          
[self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

You can either loop this, or simply set it twice, first to a BIG area and then the zoomed in area, and let the MapView's default animation do its thing.